# How can I use Azure functions or logic apps to save data into sql database?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have an ASP.NET MVC application from where I'm currently saving data into a SQL Server database.

But I want to make it loosely coupled so that is why I want to take this code out into an Azure Function or in a Logic App to save data.

Currently I use Entity Framework as it is inside the ASP.NET MVC application.

Here is a sample of the code I have:

```
private async Task SaveDatabaseAsync(List<Device> deviceDataList)
{
    // save device information into database
    _Repository.InsertMultipleDevices(deviceDataList); // used AddRange

    await _Repository.SaveAsync();

    // save message data information into database
    await SaveMessageData(deviceList);
}

private async Task SaveMessageData(List<Device> deviceListData , List<MessageData> messageDataList)
{
    // replace device id PK because device id is FK in Message table which is previously saved SaveDeviceToDatabaseAsync
    foreach (var messageData in messageDataList)
    {
        var deviceData = deviceListData.FirstOrDefault(t => Convert.ToInt32(t.Id.ToString()) == messageData.Id);
        messageData.Id = deviceData?.Id ?? 0;
    }

    MessageDataRepository _messageDataRepository = new MessageDataRepository(new IoTSimulatordbContext());
    _messageDataRepository.InsertMessageDataMultiple(messageData); // used AddRange
    await _messageDataRepository.SaveAsync();
}
```

Now I'm trying to do the same the within an Azure Function or a Logic App. Which will be better and fast if records are in thousands?

How to achieve the replace FK logic in that case ?

Comment: I am not sure I completely understand the question you are asking... Obviously, nothing prevents you from running the existing in an Azure Function or Logic App. Is the main issue related to how to have several independent Azure Function instances capable of saving data (Device - Message) that may be related?

Comment: yes , i'm thinking to create one http trigger azure function which i will trigger from mvc application and pass deviec data and message data to that azure function and i will exec stored procedure to insert device table data and message table data , will that make sense ?

Comment: What might be worth considering is to have a bunch of Azure Functions that act as a micro service that is the owner of the storage (SQL or something else actually)... That includes the saving part as well as the retrieving part...

Comment: any implementation link you  can provide a great start thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an architecture question and I strongly recommend you read the [Azure Architecture documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/). Your question is asking about a design pattern called Command Query Responsibility Separation, or CQRS. You need to consider the impact of "eventual consistency" in your database updates, which can drive a complete redesign of your database and application business logic.

My experience is that a Logic App will be quick(er) to set up than an Azure Function, however Azure Functions will perform faster and be less expensive if you have a lot of data. You also need to consider the possible impact of latency on the user experience. 
You should read this article by Troy Hunt: https://www.troyhunt.com/azure-functions-in-practice/

I have mainly used Azure Functions to update Dynamics Customer Engagement (aka CRM) and I have had to rely on using other Azure features such as Azure Service Bus to handle distribution of work across multiple functions, and handling failed transactions.